# Resize clickable area

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble on how I can adjust the click area.

Please see details below:

[image]

As you can see on the image, The cursor is way way far from the letter but still shows that it is still clickable at that distance.

Below is the code I have, I'll just show a couple of it to avoid me getting confused.

```css
li {
font-size: 20px;
display: inline;
padding-right: 20px;
border: 0px;
}

ul.list li:nth-child(-n+26) a{
font-size: 15px;
color: red;
display: list-item;
z-index: 1;
text-decoration: none;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

.onclick div:target {
display: block;
}

.onclick div:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="pageA.html">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="pageB.html">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="pageC.html">C</a></li>
      <li><a href="pageD.html">D</a></li>
      <li><a href="pageE.html">E</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
```

Already tried to add it on the multiple child style, sub nav and separate LI style, But none of it works.

Comment: If you want to make it only clickable on the letter try this styling:https://jsfiddle.net/6uvck1pt/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "width" style of a tag.

```css
ul.list li:nth-child(-n+26) a{
    width: fit-content;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful:

```css
li {
font-size: 20px;
display: inline;
padding-right: 20px;
border: 0px;
}

ul.list li:nth-child(-n+26) a{
font-size: 15px;
color: red;
display: list-item;
z-index: 1;
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0;
float: left;
clear: left;
}

.onclick div:target {
display: block;
}

.onclick div:hover {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="pageA.html">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageB.html">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageC.html">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageD.html">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="pageE.html">E</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block` to your `ul` and your problem will be fixed!